# Access Senticnet API using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple Python script as shown on the [sentic.net](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/senticnet) website:

```
from senticnet.senticnet import Senticnet
sn = Senticnet()
concept_info = sn.concept('love')
polarity = sn.polarity('love')
semantics = sn.semantics('love')
sentics = sn.sentics('love')
```

I get this warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\phyton projects\sentic parser Cambria\sentic_basic.py", line 4, in <module>
    concept_info = sn.concept('love')
  File "C:\Python27\phyton projects\sentic parser Cambria\senticnet.py", line 22, in concept
    result["polarity"] = self.polarity(concept, parsed_graph)
  File "C:\Python27\phyton projects\sentic parser Cambria\senticnet.py", line 72, in polarity
    return parsed_graph.objects(predicate=URIRef(predicate_uri)).next().toPython()
StopIteration
```

Why? How should I interpret this message?

Snippet of the code that includes the parsed_graph line:

```
def polarity(self, concept, parsed_graph=None):
    """
    Return the polarity of a concept.
    If you pass a parsed graph, the method do not load the rdf again.
    """
    concept_polarity_uri = self.concept_base_uri+concept+"/polarity"
    predicate_uri = self.senticapi_base_uri+"polarity"

    if parsed_graph is None:
        graph = rdflib.Graph()
        parsed_graph = graph.parse(concept_polarity_uri, format="xml")

    return parsed_graph.objects(predicate=URIRef(predicate_uri)).next().toPython()
```

Note: I use Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`StopIteration` means that an iterator (sort of a list) is empty, and code is asking for the next item of data.  Since there is no more data, the exception is raised.

In this case, it means `sn.polarity('love')` access something that is empty, so the program gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still exists in the latest senticnet i.e. 0.3.3. I debugged the whole thing and came across the following issues

1. The RDF/XML returned by the SenticNet API is invalid. The XML should have *'http://www.w3.org'* in place of *'http://w3.org'* everywhere (xmlns:rdf, rdf:datatype etc.). You can validate RDF data at https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/.
2. In the file *senticnet.py*, the value of *self.senticapi_base_uri* should be *'http://sentic.net'* (not *'http://sentic.net/api'*)

I modified *senticnet.py* to include a simple workaround for the aforementioned issues. I have copied the whole script below.

```
import rdflib
import urllib2
from rdflib.term import URIRef


class Senticnet(object):
    """
    Ultra simple API to use Senticnet 2 without be bothered by RDF stuff.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.concept_base_uri = "http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/"
        self.senticapi_base_uri = "http://sentic.net"

    # public methods

    def concept(self, concept):
        """
        Return all the information about a concept: semantics, sentics and polarity.
        """
        graph = rdflib.Graph()
        parsed_graph = graph.parse(data=self._fix_rdf(self.concept_base_uri+concept), format="xml")
        result = {}

        result["polarity"] = self.polarity(concept, parsed_graph)
        result["sentics"] = self.sentics(concept, parsed_graph)
        result["semantics"] = self.semantics(concept, parsed_graph)

        return result

    def semantics(self, concept, parsed_graph=None):
        """
        Return the semantics associated with a concept.
        If you pass a parsed graph, the method do not load the rdf again.
        """
        concept_semantics_uri = self.concept_base_uri+concept+"/semantics"
        semantics_predicate_uri = self.senticapi_base_uri+"semantics"

        if parsed_graph is None:
            g = rdflib.Graph()
            parsed_graph = g.parse(data=self._fix_rdf(concept_semantics_uri), format="xml")

        objects = parsed_graph.objects(predicate=URIRef(semantics_predicate_uri))
        return [self._last_uri_element(o.toPython()) for o in objects]

    def sentics(self, concept, parsed_graph=None):
        """
        Return sentics of a concept.
        If you pass a parsed graph, the method do not load the rdf again.
        """
        concept_sentics_uri = self.concept_base_uri+concept+"/sentics"
        sentics = {"pleasantness": 0, "attention": 0, "sensitivity": 0, "aptitude": 0}

        if parsed_graph is None:
            graph = rdflib.Graph()
            parsed_graph = graph.parse(data=self._fix_rdf(concept_sentics_uri), format="xml")

        for sentic in sentics.keys():
            sentics[sentic] = parsed_graph.objects(predicate=URIRef(self.senticapi_base_uri+sentic)).next().toPython()

        return sentics

    def polarity(self, concept, parsed_graph=None):
        """
        Return the polarity of a concept.
        If you pass a parsed graph, the method do not load the rdf again.
        """
        concept_polarity_uri = self.concept_base_uri+concept+"/polarity"
        predicate_uri = self.senticapi_base_uri+"polarity"

        if parsed_graph is None:
            graph = rdflib.Graph()
            parsed_graph = graph.parse(data=self._fix_rdf(concept_polarity_uri), format="xml")

        return parsed_graph.objects(predicate=URIRef(predicate_uri)).next().toPython()

    # private methods

    def _last_uri_element(self, uri):
        return uri.split("/")[-1]

    def _fix_rdf(self, concept_uri):
        return urllib2.urlopen(concept_uri).read().replace('http://w3.org','http://www.w3.org')
```

Hope this helps.